# Edit name/phone number of contact programmatically

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-contentresolver

I am trying to modify displayed name of a contact programmatically:

```
     try {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ?", new String[] {contact_id})
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, "anything")
        .build());

        ContentProviderResult[] result = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("UpdateContact", e.getMessage()+"");
        for(StackTraceElement ste : e.getStackTrace()) {
            Log.w("UpdateContact", "\t" + ste.toString());
        }
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, "Update failed", duration);
        toast.show();
    }
```

`contact_id` is `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID` gathered in previous activity

Code executes fine, but:

- `ContentProviderResult[]` result is null
- Contact name remains unchanged

I've experimented also with `Data.DISPLAY_NAME` but with same effect.

I read the Manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html but I don't want to call native intent.

Thanks.

Comment: Really? No one can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the mimetype in your selection.

```
.withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
               Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
               new String[]{contact_id})
```

If you haven't figured this out yet, give that a go. I found updating contacts to be very tricky in getting the selection arguments right.

Comment: I've figured it out some time ago, it was the clue. Thanks anyway ;).

Comment: @androfan Please post full code if you have found the answer. Thanks :)