# update contact name & number in android programmatically

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, android-cursor

I create an Application to Read, Update, Delete Contacts Details. Here is a problem to updating Contact name and number.Could anyone help me please how can I do that. I am using the following code, but it's not working.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_edit, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvnew1);

    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.newim1);
    save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.savebtn1);

    fName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.firstname1);
    lName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lastname1);
    pNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pnumber1);

    String conName = getArguments().getString("name");
    String conNumber = getArguments().getString("number");
    int conId = getArguments().getInt("pos");

    Log.e("a", "name is : " + conName);
    Log.e("a", "number is : " + conNumber);
    Log.e("a", "id is :" + conId);

    fName.setText(conName);
    pNumber.setText(conNumber);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO);
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UpdateContact(fName.getText().toString(),
                    pNumber.getText().toString(),
                    lName.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    return view;
}
public boolean UpdateContact(String name, String number, String Lastname) {
    boolean success = true;
    try {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                        new String[]{name})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
                                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                        new String[]{name})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, Lastname)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                        new String[]{name})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                .build());

        Log.e("a", "name is : " + name);
        Log.e("a", "number is : " + number);
        Log.e("a", "lastname is : " + Lastname);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=? AND " +
                                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                            new String[]{name})
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray())
                    .build());
            try {
                stream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            getActivity().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fName.setText("");
    lName.setText("");
    pNumber.setText("");
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
    imageView.destroyDrawingCache();
    return success;
}
```

My Logcat is

```
   01-31 11:52:17.298 7212-7212/com.my.fragmentmy E/a: name is : Fh
   01-31 11:52:17.298 7212-7212/com.my.fragmentmy E/a: number is : 11 2554 4
   01-31 11:52:17.298 7212-7212/com.my.fragmentmy E/a: id is :0
   01-31 11:52:31.271 7212-7212/com.my.fragmentmy E/a: name is : Fhtyttyy
   01-31 11:52:31.271 7212-7212/com.my.fragmentmy E/a: number is : 11111111 2554 4
   01-31 11:52:31.271 7212-7212/com.my.fragmentmy E/a: lastname is : rrtttt
   01-31 11:52:31.271 7212-7212/com.my.fragmentmy E/a: phoneId id : phones
```

Comment: see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887240/edit-name-phone-number-of-contact-programmatically

Comment: in logcat show name and number is change but contact not edit in the device

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private final static String[] DATA_COLS = {

    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
    ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,//phone number
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
};


public static boolean updateNameAndNumber(final Context context, String number, String newName, String newNumber) {

        if (context == null || number == null || number.trim().isEmpty()) return false;

        if (newNumber != null && newNumber.trim().isEmpty()) newNumber = null;

        if (newNumber == null) return false;


        String contactId = getContactId(context, number);

        if (contactId == null) return false;

        //selection for name
        String where = String.format(
                "%s = '%s' AND %s = ?",
                DATA_COLS[0], //mimetype
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                DATA_COLS[2]/*contactId*/);

        String[] args = {contactId};

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();

        operations.add(
                ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(where, args)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, newName)
                        .build()
        );

        //change selection for number
        where = String.format(
                "%s = '%s' AND %s = ?",
                DATA_COLS[0],//mimetype
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                DATA_COLS[1]/*number*/);

        //change args for number
        args[0] = number;

        operations.add(
                ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(where, args)
                        .withValue(DATA_COLS[1]/*number*/, newNumber)
                        .build()
        );

        try {

            ContentProviderResult[] results = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operations);

            for (ContentProviderResult result : results) {

                Log.d("Update Result", result.toString());
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }


    public static String getContactId(Context context, String number) {

        if (context == null) return null;

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "=?",
                new String[]{number},
                null
        );

        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) return null;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));

        cursor.close();
        return id;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Contacts {


    public static boolean addContactList(Context context,int id, String contactName, String contactNumber){


        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Name
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contactName);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Number
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contactNumber);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME);
        ops.add(builder.build());
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static HashMap<String,String> getContactList(Context context){

        HashMap<String,String> contact = new HashMap<>();

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL}, null, null, null);

        if(null != c){
            String data = "";
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                if(c.getString(3) != null){
                    data = c.getString(0)+" "+c.getString(1)+" "+c.getString(2)+" "+c.getString(3)+"\n";
                    //position 0 - id
                    //position 1 - contact
                    //position 2 - type
                    //position 3 - label/name
                    contact.put(c.getString(3),c.getString(1));
                }
            }
            c.close();
        }
        return  contact;
    }


    public static boolean updateContactList(Context context,String name,String newPhoneNumber){
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";

        String[] params = new String[] {name,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)};
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, params)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA, newPhoneNumber)
                .build());
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

        public static boolean deleteContactList(Context context,String name){
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ";
            String[] params = new String[] {name};

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where, params)
                    .build());
            try {
                cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

    public static boolean contactExists(Context context, String name) {
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(name));
        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                return true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (cur != null)
                cur.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

hope this works.

Comment: yes but in logcat show name and number is change but contact not edit in the device

Answer (score 1):

I might be late with the answer, but this one has worked for me. The main difference from other answers was that instead of `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID`, I've used `ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID`. When you get the Contact object query for `raw_id` - `rawContactId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID));`

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();

            String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

            String[] nameParams = new String[]{rawContactId,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
            String[] numberParams = new String[]{rawContactId,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

            final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

            if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(
                        android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(where, nameParams)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                name).build());
            }
            if (!number.isEmpty()) {
                ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(
                        android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(where, numberParams)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                        .build());
            }
            contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Answer (score 1):

***Be careful!***

Some mobiles e.g The samsung edge series put extra white space in mobile numbers. So for e.g the number `01234567` will be saved like `012 23467`. So Be Sure that number still have white space when you querying with Where clause.

if you have Raw contact id in hand then you should get all the numbers from that contact and check number while removing extra spaces.

`number = number.replaceAll("[\\s|\\u00A0]+", ""); would remove extra space`