# Is it possible to update emergency contact programatically?

Tags: android, android-contacts, lockscreen, android-dialer

I am able to make a call using,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "911"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I am required to update emergency contact in Android programatically from my app. Is there any way to update emergency contact from any app other than from default contact app? By update I mean add, delete and modify any emergency contact.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41950741/1084174) is one post, where they discussed how to update contact, but in my case, I need to update the emergency contact not a normal contact.

Comment: I don't think that anybody except the user should be able to do that. I think that it would create the danger to the user's life if some 3rd-party app was able to change emergency contact.

Comment: Only system apps can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to modify emergency information until now. However any app can ask user to edit info using `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_EDIT`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```