# Android Contacts update creating duplicate record instead of updating records

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

I am trying to simply update various fields of a contact from my application. The result from my code is that instead of updating the records, another record is added and joined to the contact. My code is below. Any observable reasons as to why this is the case?

```
String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> opsUpdate = new ArrayList<>();

        opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString())
                .build());
        opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, emailTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString())
                .build());
        opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL, websiteTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString())
                .build());
        opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE, notesTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString())
                .build());
        opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, nameTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString())
                .build());
        if (professionTextInputLayout2.getEditText().getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA4, professionTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString())
                    .build());
        } else {
            opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA4, professionTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString() + "/" + professionTextInputLayout2.getEditText().getText().toString())
                    .build());
        }
        opsUpdate.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(orgWhere, new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, locationTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString())
                .build());

        try {
            ContentProviderResult[] res = this.getContentResolver().applyBatch(
                    ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, opsUpdate);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887240/edit-name-phone-number-of-contact-programmatically?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: when you say "creating duplicate record" you mean it's creating a duplicate contact? if so, verify that the contact-id you're providing is correct, if it isn't instead of modifying the right contact, you're taking a completely different contact and converting it to be a duplicate of the real one

Comment: also, I would never update `DATA` records based on selection of `CONTACT_ID` this may have unintended consequences if the contact is made up of multiple raw-contacts. Instead either use the `RAW_CONTACT_ID` or even better the Data._ID of the specific row you wish to modify

Comment: @marmor Zooming in it seems like I am inserting a new Raw Contact with every update. I found that one of my issues is stemming from my details screen where once again I am getting the contacts details from Data.CONTACT_ID. I'm going through the Contacts Provider documentation for clarity and then will try to use the Contacts.Entity manner of querying for all details of a RawContact. If you have any experience with the Contact.Entity process it would be helpful to see a sample.

Comment: I am currently able to get the contacts details through the Contact.Entity rows. However my updates still add a new Raw Contacts instead of editing an already existing Raw Contacts. Any guesses why is appreciated.